# Filling a column with an an equation in r

Tags: r, formula

I am just getting used to r and need to populate a new column in my data frame with the following equation

```
exp(-(["column a"]^2/(2*10^2))
```

Sorry if this is really obvious but I would greatly appreciate if anyone can help in writing this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question seems to be quite incomplete, so as far as I understand you're looking for something like this

```
> DF <- data.frame(a=1:6, b=2*(1:6)) # A dummy data.frame
> transform(DF, newColumn=exp(-(a^2/(2*10^2)))) # the eq you want to apply
  a  b newColumn
1 1  2 0.9950125
2 2  4 0.9801987
3 3  6 0.9559975
4 4  8 0.9231163
5 5 10 0.8824969
6 6 12 0.8352702

> DF$newColumn2 <- exp(-(DF[,"a"]^2/(2*10^2))) # the eq you want to apply other alternative
> DF
  a  b newColumn2
1 1  2  0.9950125
2 2  4  0.9801987
3 3  6  0.9559975
4 4  8  0.9231163
5 5 10  0.8824969
6 6 12  0.8352702
```

Comment: Ah so simple, its too late at night for me.  Thank you

Comment: I would but I appear to need to raise my reputation before I can upvote.